# Error when trying to virtualize linux 5 in AMD ryzen 3

Tags: virtualbox, vmware, 19.04

I'm trying to install a virtual machine with Virtual box and Vmware. I can create a virtual machine with Ubuntu 18.04 without problem, but when I try to create a virtual machine with Ubuntu 19 or Kubuntu 19, with linux version 5, the instalation fails like you can see in the next image.

[image: error]

Do you have the same problem or is just a bad configuration of windows 10?

Thank you so much!

VMware configuration
[image: CPU]

VirtualBox configuration:
[image: VBox]

Comment: What version of VirtualBox are you using?

Comment: @ajgringo619 6.0 the lastest version 6.0 and VMware version is 15.01

Comment: You may want to try VB v6.0.8. I ran v6.0.10 on Linux Mint and found it not nearly as stable as the previous release. Can you post (add to your question) your current VB VM config?

Comment: Same problem with v6.0.8 I think is beacuse Linux 5.0 kernel but I dont know why. Ubuntu 18.04 works. @ajgringo619

Comment: I'm seeing a few complaints about VB (Windows Host) on the VB forums, but nothing specific to the kernel version. Try installing the 5.x kernel on your Ubuntu 18.04 VM.

Comment: It works with linux 5.0 umm so is not linux kernel version. So... what could be the problem? The image? maybe doesnt have compatibility with new ryzen? @ajgringo619

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97694/discussion-between-ajgringo619-and-sermanes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed with Bios updates. Need to update bios so the ryzen AMD processors can use LINUX 5.